# How important is memory release for iPhone Apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-management

I am a beginner of Objective C. I know java programming and in the intro level course, memory release is not covered (and I don't know whether there is one in a more advanced level course or java complier handles this). However, even at the intro level I need to manually release memory for Objective C program. I know it's a good habit to do this but just how important is it? Especially if I want to develop iPhone apps, is memory release very urgent (and not doing this will result in significant slowing of processing)? By iPhone apps, I am not talking about big 3D games with fantastic visual effects, high-quality sound effects, and other stuff that may make memory release important. I just want to develop some small tools such as calculator, reminder, or diary book. So how important is memory release?

I think memory release was important in old days, when C language program was run on super old computers which might not have too much memory and processing speed. But considering iPhone is a pretty advanced device, is manual memory release a little bit out-dated?

Comment: This question is not really a good fit for SO. This site is more for specific technical issues. If I were you, I'd continue reading about Objective-C and increase my knowledge of the subject, then bring any specific questions to the attention of SO.

Comment: Sorry if it's unfit. I'm just frustrated by the manual work of releasing memory and I want to know whether I should be serious and careful when reading about memory release in my textbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know java programming and in the intro level course, memory release is not covered (and I don't know whether there is one in a more advanced level course or java complier handles this).

Not exactly the compiler, but the Java VM has a garbage collector, so one does not have to worry about memory management.

> So how important is memory release?

**Very important.** Be it the runtime or the programmer who does it, regardless of whether you use MRC or ARC (in Objective-C), you should keep the memory fingerprint of your app as low as possible by properly managing memory.

> I think memory release was important in old days, when C language program was run on super old computers which might not have too much memory and processing speed. But considering iPhone is a pretty advanced device, is manual memory release a little bit out-dated?

Oh. I just understood why a lot of apps eat up all the free RAM of my iPhone. So that's because this is the attitude of "developers" nowadays. I see...

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you are doing.  In general, it is very important for memory to be released properly or it will build up and eat up all the ram.  This will happen quickly for something like a game, or will happen very slowly for something with just text and numbers, although it will still be there.  However, memory release is not as hard as it sounds.  If you are using ARC, you can almost forget about it (beware there are some weird cases though).  Even if you are not using ARC, Apple does a lot for you, like calling release on objects at logical times (like when removing a viewController).

Also, memory management generally only applies to using object oriented code.  If you are just making a simple calculator, you will likely not need anything object oriented, and you can just work in floats.  There will be no memory management for a simple app that just deals with floats.

Comment: I challange you to make an iPhone app that *only* uses primitive types and no objects!

Comment: Yeah, I think the basic paradigm of iPhone Apps Programming is OOP. The XCode automatically create the view and controller objects and you need to make the model. Also, Foundation and UIKit are just collections of objects.

Comment: If you are creating the simplest calculator app, all of the objects are dealt with through Interface Builder, except for when you are updating your UILabel or however you are displaying your answer, which should be a very simple case, taken care of by ARC.  The rest of the code is primitive types.